# Sed replace inside a json file with regex

Tags: linux, sed, jq

I have a huge json file, i will copy a part of it :

```
"panels": [
 "targets": [
{
  "alias": "First Prod",
  "dimensions": {
    "Function": "robot-support-dev-create-human"
  },
}
{
  "alias": "Second Prod",
  "dimensions": {
    "Function": "robot-support-prototype-dev-beta-activate-human"
  },
}
{
  "alias": "third Prod",
  "dimensions": {
    "Function": "robot-support-dev-jira-kill-human"
  },
}  
{
   "alias": "Somehting",


 "dimensions": {
    "Robotalias": "default",
    "RobotName": "Robot-prod-prototype",
    "Operation": "Fight"
  },
]
]
```

I want to perform a Regex on Function each time it contains the `robot-support-dev` to `robot-support-prod-...`

```
sed -i ' s/"robot-support-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)-dev-([^"]+)"/robot-support-\\1-prod-\\2/g;'
```

This is what i did but there's something wrong with my regex maybe

Comment: Please provide a valid JSON data sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can't match a json with a regex. The "right way(TM)" would be to first extract `Function` using a json aware tool like `jq`, then modify it with `sed`, then insert it back using json aware tool.

Sed by default uses [basic regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html), so you need to change `(` `)` `+` into `\(` `\)` `\{1,\}` (the `\+` is a GNU extension) or with GNU sed just use `sed -E` to use extended regex. Also the `\\1` would be interpreted as 2 characters `\` with `1`, you want to use `\1` with a single `\`. But anyway, your regex is just invalid and does not match what you want (I guess). Also the `"` are missing on the right side in the replacement string, so your command would just remove the `"`. Just substitute what you need, try:

```
sed 's/"robot-support-dev-/"robot-support-prod-/g;'
```

Answer (score 0):

As @KamilCuk pointed out, there are some issues with the regex you are currently using. I think that if the occurrences you give as an example are the only possibilities, it would work if you match these groups:

```
sed -i 's/"robot-support\(-\|-.*-\)dev-\(.*\)"/"robot-support\1prod-\2"/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out elsewhere on this page, using `sed` for this type of problem is, at best, fraught with danger. Since the question has been tagged with [jq](/questions/tagged/jq), it should be pointed out that jq is an excellent match for this type of problem. In particular, a trivial solution can be obtained using the filter `sub` of arity 2 or 3, i.e. `sub/3`: sub("FROM"; "TO"; "g").

You might also wish to use `walk` so that you don't have to be concerned about where exactly the "Function" keys occur, e.g.

```
walk( if type == "object" and (.Function|type) == "string"
      then .Function |= sub( "robot-support-(?<a>([^-]+-)?)dev-"; "robot-support-\(.a)prod-"; "g")
      else . end)
```